# convert to IQueryable set of results

Tags: c#, .net, linq

We return `completedFilters.Select(GetFilterDetailDril)`

We have very complicated logic in  `GetFilterDetailDril` that calls lots of functions.
It's kind of impossible to write all of that in rows select without call functions the problem is we want to export it later and we should that it will be queryable. 
But if we call functions the c# can't make it queryable any more.
is there a solution?

that is what I return

```
return filtersInDevelopment.Select(GetFilterDetailDrillDownModel)
```

this is the function

```
private FilterDevDetailDrillDownModel GetFilterDetailDrillDownModel(ALFilters alFilters)
    {
        alFilters = (alFilters.IsSample == 1 && alFilters.DestFilters.FirstOrDefault() != null) 
            ? alFilters.DestFilters.FirstOrDefault() : alFilters;
        var alFiltersDevelopment = alFilters.AlFiltersDevelopment.FirstOrDefault();

        if (alFiltersDevelopment != null)
        {
            var repository = new FilterRepository();
            var adt = alFiltersDevelopment.Adt ?? repository.GetAdt(alFilters);
            var edt = alFiltersDevelopment.Edt ?? repository.GetEdt(alFilters);

            var filterActiveMilestone = alFilters.FilterActiveMilestone;

            var milestoneTargetDate = (filterActiveMilestone != null)
                                          ? filterActiveMilestone.TargetDate
                                          : repository.GetFilterActiveMilestoneTargetDate(alFilters);

            var firstDevMilestone = alFilters.FilterMilestones.FirstOrDefault(
                x => x.MilestoneTypeId == FilterConst.START_DEVELOPMENT_MILESTONE);

            var startDevTime = (firstDevMilestone != null)
                                   ? firstDevMilestone.MilestoneDate
                                   : (DateTime?) null;

            string milestoneNmae = (filterActiveMilestone != null)
                                       ? filterActiveMilestone.dic_MilestoneTypes.NameForReport
                                       : string.Empty;

            double remainingMilestoneTime = (milestoneTargetDate.HasValue)
                                                ? milestoneTargetDate.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days
                                                : 0;

            double delayedTime = (edt != null && adt != null)
                                     ? adt.Value.Subtract(edt.Value).Days
                                     : 0 ;
            var site = db.dic_AL_Sites.Find(alFilters.SiteId);
            return new FilterDevDetailDrillDownModel
                {
                    FilterId = alFilters.ID,
                    Filter = alFilters.FilterCode,
                    StartDevDate = startDevTime,
                    MilelstoneName = milestoneNmae,
                    RemainingMilestoneTime = remainingMilestoneTime,
                    MilestoneEstimatedFinishDate = milestoneTargetDate,
                    EstimatedDevelopmentTime = alFiltersDevelopment.Edt,
                    DelayedTime = delayedTime,
                    Site = (site != null) ? site.Site_Name : string.Empty
                };
        }
        return null;
    }
```

lots of logic...
i want i queriable return but this is not iqueriable this filtersInDevelopment.Select(GetFilterDetailDrillDownModel) is enumerable without possibility to see query :(

Comment: so much edit no one answer?

Comment: Please add some more code and valid info, which make us some sense of what you are asking.

Comment: use .AsQueryable() at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Types that implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface can be converted to an `IQueryable<T>` by invoking the `AsQueryable<T>` extension method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003(v=vs.110).aspx

There is a non-generic equivalent, too:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: but can i export that later? when i click with mouse on that or add quick warch i cant see the query after convert. like in iqueriable means select bla bla bla..

Comment: What query? The expression tree? I think there is some information you're not telling us here. Are your LINQ statements acting on pure CLR objects, or are they accessing an Entity Framework context, or NHibernate, or....? It's easier for us to help if you don't make us guess.

Comment: edited the question with all the things